# Could've previous owner installed tracking software on my phone, even if I changed the SIM card?

Tags: phone, software

I recently bought a used mobile Android phone. Is there any way to install malware, tracking software etc. that is not on the SIM card, but on some other kind of memory disc?

Answer (score 2):

> I recently bought a used mobile Android phone. Is there any way to install malware, tracking software etc. that is not on the SIM card, but on some other kind of memory disc?

Yes.  When you buy a phone, you're trusting that the phone doesn't have malicious software installed on it.  Even the factory reset could potentially be compromised if the phone itself has been rooted and the OS replaced with a malicious version that doesn't perform a full reset.

In practice, it's unlikely that a phone you buy used has a malicious OS installed, so a factory reset is (likely) going to be sufficient to clear out any tracking software installed by a previous owner.

Of course, your paranoia may vary :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  SIM cards have very little memory.  It's more likely that malware would be in the phone itself than on a SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another question where the real answer is "yes, anything is possible, but unlikely".

The SIM card is probably the last thing I'd worry about. On Android, a factory reset typically wipes the data partition, the internal "SD card", and possibly some other ephemeral locations. Notably, it does not touch the system or boot partitions, or the bootloader. These partitions can be modified by unlocking the bootloader and/or rooting the phone (depending on vendor). Malicious changes could be made to these locations, but it is rather unlikely that you will encounter them.

However, there are some ways you may be able to verify or at least increase trust in the device (never 100%). First, if the device does not have an unlockable bootloader or known root method, it is very unlikely a change could be made to those important locations. Second, depending on the phone, it may be possible to download and flash the factory images onto the device, eliminating any changes. Third, modern versions of Android ship with [verified boot](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/), which uses cryptography to ensure that critical system partitions haven't changed. This could at least tell you whether the device has been modified, as long as the keys haven't been changed.

Answer (score -1):

If you bought a used phone the first thing you should do is "factory reset". Doing so you ensure that you won't have any malicious software on your phone.

Comment: If you root the phone you can replace the factory image, so this doesn't really ensure that you're left with a safe phone.